# What is a real-world analogy for an aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design

When I take a look at our office, some entities and value objects immediately come to my mind.

E.g., an empty post-it from a block of post-its is for sure a value object, as it can not be distinguished from any other empty post-it on the same block, and I don't really care at all about *which* post-it I use if I need an empty one.

In contrast, me and my co-workers are for sure entities, because each of us has an identity.

A table might be an entity or a value object, depending on the way you look at it (is it just any table quite as good as any other, or is it *your* table?).

Of course, YMMV.

So, now that I've found some real-world analogies to entities and value objects - what would be an analogy for an aggregate? Is there one?

I could imagine that getting the idea of what an aggregate is in reality helps to understand the concept behind it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is conceptual and better asked at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example in blue book:A car.

A car (entity, identified by vehicle identification number) have 4 wheels (entity, identified by left front, left rear , right front, right rear).

I dont need to (and want to) know how the wheels works when I drive a car. The car entity encapsulates them for me as an aggregate root.

Another example in blue book: A purchase order.

At any time, the total amount of sub-purchase orders(local entity) can not be greater than the limit of the purcahse order(aggregate root in this case). The aggregate root should check constraints  all the time.